# Using CocoaPods breaks build

Tags: xcode4.5, cocoapods

I took a **fully working** Xcode project and added a Podfile to it.  After doing the pod install, opening the newly created workspace and trying to build, it no longer works.  When I compile now I get errors from a couple system header files.  For example, NSFetchRequestExpression.h tells me:

> Attempting to use the forward class 'NSExpression' as superclass of 'NSFetchRequestExpression'

I manually went in and added $(inherited) to the front of the "Framework Search Paths" and "Other Linker Flags" build settings.  Any ideas on what I need to change to make this work?

Comment: What's in your `Podfile`?

Comment: platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'TestFlightSDK'
pod 'AFNetworking'

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out.  CocoaPods actually changes the way includes work.  I had a core data entity called Time, which creates and NSManagedObject subclass called Time.h.  When CocoaPods mucks with the header include search paths, suddenly the system files which asked for  found my time file instead.  I renamed that class (which I shouldn't have had to do!) and now everything works fine.